# Finding the average from user given list in python

Tags: python

I need to get the user to input the grades of both "boys" and "girls" until they want to stop adding the grades. Than find the average of the boys grades and the average of the girls and print them both separately.

My issue is I don't understand how i'm supposed to make it so the user can add as many grades as they want for both the boys and the girls, and then get both of the averages.

I'm still very new to python and am not sure what the best method for this would be, like would I use `while` or `if` in some way that I haven't learned yet?

Comment: How would you do it in your head or on paper ? Keep a running total of boy grades and girl grades then divide by the number of boys/girls.

Comment: I don't know how to make it so the user can continuously add more grades, and then once that's over how would my code know the number of grades to divide by.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. One would be to have the user type numbers separated by newlines until they entered a special string, like "done". Another would be to have the user enter the name of a file where they entered the grades. Until you have a good conceptual idea of what you want your program to do, trying to code it is rather futile.

Comment: Make an infinite while loop and put an end condition. It's like enter as many as you want and when you entered `OK!` loop will stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bn,bs=0,0 #count of boys,Sum of grades of boys
gn,gs=0,0 #Count of girls, Sum of grades of girls
while(1):
    grades=input("Enter grades = ") #Enter grades as 10b where 10 is grade and "b"->boys "g"->girls or any other character to quit.
    if('b' in grades):
        bs+=int(grades.replace('b',''))
        bn+=1
    else:
        if('g' in grades):
            gs+=int(grades.replace('g',''))
            gn+=1
        else:
            if(bn!=0): #Divide by zero error
                print("Average of boys = "+ str(bs/bn))
            if(gn!=0):
                print("Average of girls = "+ str(gs/gn))
            break
```